# What PHP file(s) in Wordpress is/are reponsible for creating the layout of the inner pages generated by "Add Pages"?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, layout

I'm currently into studying wordpress files structure. Which PHP file or PHP files are responsible for creating the layout of the inner pages in Wordpress? How do you manipulate them? I know css is a simple answer but where the PHP files that contain the div tags and all?

Currently, I know a bit about manipulating the header and footer in wordpress but not the pages generated by "add pages".

I hope you can help..

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

under your theme folder check `page.php` file